# Adding special characters in sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

In `SQLPlus`, how do I add string that contains a special character to my database? The special character I am trying to use is 'é'.

I've tried Aim(atl+130) which is: Aimé but returns 'Aim?'

Answer (score 0):

I copied your character and did this to find the value 233:

```
select dump('é') from dual;
```

So you should be able to do this and get it back (of course you can `INSERT` it too):

```
select 'Aim' || chr(233) from dual;
```